# Symfony not redirecting after login

Tags: php, symfony

My code does not give a message when I make a failed attempt to login nor does it redirect when I actually do login. Is there any chance someone can help me?

```
security.yml
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                inkoper:
                    password: TeslaModelS
                    roles: 'ROLE_INKOPER'
                admin:
                    password: GoudenEikel
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
                verkoper:
                    password: Barracuda
                    roles: 'ROLE_INKOPER'
                magazijnmeester:
                    password: kitten
                    roles: 'ROLE_MAGAZIJNMEESTER'

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/artikel/alle, roles: [ROLE_INKOPER, ROLE_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/artikel/wijzig/*, roles: [ROLE_INKOPER, ROLE_MAGAZIJNMEESTER] }
    - { path: ^/artikel/verwijder/* , roles: ROLE_INKOPER }
    - { path: ^/artikel/magazijnlocatie/* , roles: ROLE_MAGAZIJNMEESTER }
    - { path: ^/artikel/* , roles: ROLE_INKOPER }
    - { path: ^/* , roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /artikel/alle
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        http_basic: ~

        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
        #form_login: ~
```

This is my controller

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request){
$authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

// get the login error if there is one
$error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

// last username entered by the user
$lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

return $this->render('login.html.twig', array(
    'last_username' => $lastUsername,
    'error'         => $error,
));
}
}
```

and this is the twig I am using

```
{% if error %}
<div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

{#
    If you want to control the URL the user
    is redirected to on success (more details below)
    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/artikel/alle" />
#}

<button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your form action should probably be `login_check` instead of `login`. Either create a route for it or put it into the template statically (like you did in the config). Alternatively, if you followed the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html), note that they use the same route (`login`) for the `login_path` and `check_path` `security.yml` directive.

Comment: sadly enough this did not work, and I have to say I am very new to this. So I don't fully understand what to change :)

Comment: But i changed the (login)

Comment: Leave everything as posted in the original question and change the `check_path` in your `security.yml` to `login`.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Now I have to figure the logout function out!

Comment: Logging out is as simple as linking to `/logout` (More info: [Link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#logging-out)).

Comment: yeah found out it was easy as that :) Now I am struggling with querys. Well one struggle at a time while I try to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, have you tried to use the route name instead of the path in the default_target_path key of your security.yml ?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.